# Agora start Cloud Recording returns 400 with no error message

Tags: agora.io

I'm trying to set up Cloud Recording for Agora. I'm able to call the acquire method and obtain a Resource ID, but when I try to start recording I get a 400 response that has no error code or reason message. If I change any part of the request body I will get an error code of 2 with a reason message, so I think my request is formatted properly. Also, since the first request to acquire the resource ID is successful, I don't think there should be an authentication issue. The code to generate the RTC Token is being used elsewhere to create the channel and users are able to join channels in the app.

```
    requestBody := fmt.Sprintf(`
        {
            "cname": "%s",
            "uid": "%d",
            "clientRequest": {
                "token": "%s",
                "recordingConfig": {
                    "maxIdleTime": 30,
                    "streamTypes": 0,
                    "channelType": 1,
                    "transcodingConfig": {
                        "height": 720,
                        "width": 1280,
                        "bitrate": 2260,
                        "fps": 15,
                        "mixedVideoLayout": 1,
                        "backgroundColor": "#000000"
                    }
                },
                "storageConfig": {
                    "vendor": %d,
                    "region": %d,
                    "bucket": "%s",
                    "accessKey": "%s",
                    "secretKey": "%s",
                    "fileNamePrefix": ["tracks"]
                }
            }
        }
    `, channelID, uid, rtcToken, 1 /*AWS*/, region, os.Getenv("AGORA_BUCKET_NAME"),
        os.Getenv("AGORA_BUCKET_ACCESS_KEY"), os.Getenv("AGORA_BUCKET_ACCESS_SECRET"),
        channelID)

    reqUrl := "https://api.agora.io/v1/apps/" + os.Getenv("AGORA_APP_ID") + "/cloud_recording/resourceid/" + rid + "/mode/mix/start"
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", reqUrl,
        bytes.NewBuffer([]byte(requestBody)))
    if err != nil {
        return response, err
    }

    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    req.SetBasicAuth(os.Getenv("AGORA_CUSTOMER_ID"), os.Getenv("AGORA_CUSTOMER_CERTIFICATE"))

    resp, err := httpClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return response, err
    }

    if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        // this is a 400 with no error code or reason
        logger.Log("statuscode", resp.StatusCode)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are able to get a `resourceID` is because your appID has Cloud Recording enable and a `400` response from `start` means your request is properly formatted and successfully making the call to start the Agora Cloud Recorder instance but something is causing the Agora Cloud Recorder to fail to start.

Have you tried using the [Agora Postman collection](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/6319646/SVSLr9AM) to test? I would recommend using it within Postman because it offers a working config that requires you to set your connection credentials into the variables and it should work if your bucket is properly configured.

[I wrote this quick-start guide](https://medium.com/agora-io/agora-cloud-recording-quickstart-guide-with-postman-demo-c4a6b824e708) on how to set up Cloud Recording and use the Postman collection to test.

Comment: Make sure to check the Bucket Region you are sending within your request. That’s a common mistake is not setting the correct region.